# See swift stdout for a react-native application

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, stdout

Say I have the following React Native code:

```
import { NativeModules, Platform } from 'react-native'

if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
  NativeModules.ExampleThing.exampleMethod('example')
}
```

The following Swift class:

```
@objc(ExampleThing)
class ExampleThing: NSObject {
  private override init() {
    print('init')
  }

  @objc func exampleMethod(_ message: String) -> Void {
    print(message)
    //do more complex thing
  }
}
```

and the following bridging header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(ExampleThing, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(exampleMethod:(NSString *)message)
@end
```

When I run `react-native run-ios`, the app starts in the simulator just fine, e.g: the effect of `exampleMethod` (send a message to Segment.IO) occurs, ergo `exampleMethod` is quite clearly getting called correctly. However, for the life of me, I can not find where the print command is printing to. I've also tried os_log

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to run the project through XCode instead of `react-native run-ios`, and it'll be shown on the XCode output console.

You can also make use of XCode's breakpoints etc instead of `print` statements to help in debugging.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without running through XCode? My app has never been able to run through XCode (although it builds through react-native, and fastlane, and deploys to production, and runs on user's devices, and I have already burned days in that particular hell dimension and would like to avoid a return if at all possible....)

as an aside, pre edit you suggested `log-ios`, this does not print the `print` output, and just prints things like `com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.82AB0620-7359-4648-A5C2-99D80895029B[42944] (com.apple.videosubscriptionsd) <Notice>: Service only ran ...`

Comment: Yeah I don't think `log-ios` can print native code, see [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#debugging-native-code). Try and see if you can run a fresh RN project on simulator through XCode.